# how give value to class member in php

Tags: c#, php

I have a method in php that I need to call and send some variable to it. This is where I am calling the method:

```
$param = array (
'AuthenticationKey' => $authkey,
'vconfig' => ?,
'vcondition' =>$vcondition,
'ZipCode' =>$ZipCode,
'VersionDate' => $currentdate,
);


$result = $client->call('GetVehicleValuesByVehicleConfiguration', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
```

One of the variable that I am sending to this method is class (`'vconfig' => ?`) this one.
I am not sure how to initialize that class, its members, and send it as a parameter to this method.

I have used this to initialize the class:

```
  $vconfig = new  $client.VehicleConfiguration;
```

but another method is giving me some values that I need to pass to this class, I am not sure how. I have made the code working in C# but don't know how to make it in php. That is what I am talking about in C#.

```
   ServiceReference1.VehicleConfiguration vconfig = new ServiceReference1.VehicleConfiguration();


  var getValue2 = soapClient.GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleId(AuthenticationId, ap, 2, "01602", current);


          //dont know how to do this part in php
         vconfig.Year = getValue2.Year;
         vconfig.Make = getValue2.Make;
         vconfig.Model = getValue2.Model;
         vconfig.Trim = getValue2.Trim;
         vconfig.Mileage = getValue2.Mileage;
         vconfig.OptionalEquipment = getValue2.OptionalEquipment;
```

I don't know how to do the last part `vconfig.Year = getValue2.Year;` in php
This is the code of web service class that I need to give value to the elements:

```
   public partial class VehicleConfiguration : object,    System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private int IdField;

    private string VINField;

    private ConsumeKbbAPI.ServiceReference1.IdStringPair YearField;

    private ConsumeKbbAPI.ServiceReference1.IdStringPair MakeField;

    private ConsumeKbbAPI.ServiceReference1.IdStringPair ModelField;

    private ConsumeKbbAPI.ServiceReference1.IdStringPair TrimField;
    //private ConsumeKbbAPI.ServiceReference1.VehicleTrim TrimField;



    private int MileageField;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Configuration class, but if you have public members as in C#, this could work:

```
<?php

//Example of class
class Configuration {
  public $year;
  public $model;
  //and so on
}

//Example of instantiation
$vconfig = new Configuration();

//Here's the syntax you're looking for
$vconfig->year = 2002;
$vconfig->model = "Something";
```

Comment: Thanks, if my class is in web service what I should have? that is my webservice: $client = new nusoap_client('https://idw.sy.com/3.0/VehicleInformationService2008R2.svc?wsdl', 'wsdl',
      $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);
and that is a way I initialize the class: $vconfig = new  $client.VehicleConfiguration;   VehicleConfiguration is the name of the class in webservice.

Comment: If the members of your class are public, you could do: `vconfig->Year = getValue2->Year;` (and so on for each value). Otherwise, it depends on the public interface of your class

Comment: members are private. I have added the code of webservice class (that is in C#) to my question.

Comment: but in c# after I init the class I have access to the elemet like. config.Year , config.make and so one....